# how can i check json response has own property with switch case?

Tags: javascript, json

```
switch (res) {
case res.hasOwnProperty('userName'):
console.log('a');
break;
}
```

how can i check  json response has own property with switch case ?

this is my json object

```
{
"userName": [
    "فقط حروف فارسی را وارد کنید"
],
"userLname": [
    "نام خانوادگی بنمیتواند خالی باشد"
],
"userAddress": [
    "آدرس صحیح نیست",
    "فقط حروف فارسی را وارد کنید"
],
"userWeb": [
    "آدرس وبسایت وارد شده اشتباه است ",
    "دامنه وارد شده صحیح نیست"
],
"userTeleid": [
    "حروف انگلیسی را فقط ساپورت میکند"
],
"userInsta": [
    "حروف انگلیسی را فقط ساپورت میکند"
]
```

}

Can the switch do this correctly? Are all items checked in order?

Answer (score 3):

> Can the switch do this correctly?

Yes, but that's really not what `switch` is for. Use `if`:

```
if (res.hasOwnProperty('userName')) {
    console.log('a');
}
```

---

The way to do it with `switch` (**don't do this!**) is:

```
switch (true) {
    case res.hasOwnProperty('userName'):
        console.log('a');
        break;
}
```

That works because in JavaScript (unlike some other languages), `case` labels are expressions. The `switch` expression is evaluated and then each `case` expression is evaluated and tested against the `switch` expression using strict equality (`===`).

Or you could do this (which would work in most languages, not just JavaScript);

```
switch (res.hasOwnProperty('userName')) {
    case true:
        console.log('a');
        break;
}
```

But again: **Don't do that.** Use an `if`. That's what it's for. :-)

Answer (score 0):

why not simply

```
if ('userName' in res) {
   ...
}
```

?
...if for any reason You HAVE to use a `switch` You can still write it like:

```
switch(true) {
  case 'userName' in res:
    // ...
    break;
  case 'userLname' in t:
    // ...
    break;
  // ...
}
```

but I do **NOT** recommend it, the `if` version does a great job there

Comment: The OP has specifically said they want to check for an **own** property. `in` checks the prototype chain. (Now, it's unlikely to matter, since `userName` isn't a property on `Object.prototype` and if this is parsed JSON, the object will inherit directly from `Object.prototype`, but still, "use `in`'" isn't an answer to "I want to check for an own property.")

Comment: @T.J.Crowder u are right.. thus only `hasOwnProperty` can do that (given he wants to avoid the prototype props, regardless the depth)

Answer (score 0):

I would rather store the properties you want to check in an array and iterate over it :

```js
const res = {
"userName": [
    "فقط حروف فارسی را وارد کنید"
],
"userLname": [
    "نام خانوادگی بنمیتواند خالی باشد"
],
"userAddress": [
    "آدرس صحیح نیست",
    "فقط حروف فارسی را وارد کنید"
],
"userWeb": [
    "آدرس وبسایت وارد شده اشتباه است ",
    "دامنه وارد شده صحیح نیست"
],
"userTeleid": [
    "حروف انگلیسی را فقط ساپورت میکند"
],
"userInsta": [
    "حروف انگلیسی را فقط ساپورت میکند"
]}

const propertiesToCheck = ["userName", "userLname", "userWeb", "foo"];

propertiesToCheck.forEach(property =>
{
    if (res.hasOwnProperty(property))
        console.log(property + " exists");
    else
        console.log(property + " does not exist");
});
```